# Poisson: $P(N(4)-N(2)=5|N(4)=8)$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, markov-chains, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Let {N(t), t ≥ 0} be a Poisson process of rate 2. Determine:

a) $P(N(4)-N(2)=5|N(4)=8)$

**Attempt:**
The conditional poisson distribution is uniformly distributed between the interval [0,4].
Therefore, this would be binomial distributed with probaiblity $p=1/2$

### $P(N(2)=3|N(4)=8)=$ $8\choose3$$(1/2)^8$

---

b) $E(N(4)-N(2)|N(3)=1)$

**Attempt:**
This part I really not sure. I break it into two cases. The first case is when the even $N(3)=1$ happens between [0,2], this has probaiblty 2/3.
If it happens between [2,3], it has probaiblity 1/3.

Therefore, $E(N(4)-N(2)|N(3)=1)=(1/3)(\lambda +1)+(2/3)(2\lambda)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes.   We could *also* use the definition of Conditional Probability, and the fact that *the count of Poisson events occurring in disjoint intervals* are independent.

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(N(4)-N(2)=3\mid N(4)=8) ~=~& \dfrac{\mathsf P(N(2)=5)~\mathsf P(N(4)-N(2)=3)}{\mathsf P(N(4)=8)}
\\ =~& \dfrac{((2\lambda)^5\mathsf e^{-2\lambda}/5!)~((2\lambda)^3\mathsf e^{-2\lambda}/3!)}{(4\lambda)^8\mathsf e^{-4\lambda}/8!}
\\ =~& \binom{8}{3}\frac 1{2^8}
\end{align}$$

---

2. No.   For this you need to use Linearity of Expectation:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(N(4)-N(2)\mid N(3)=1) ~=~ & \mathsf E(N(4)\mid N(3)=1)-\mathsf E(N(2)\mid N(3)=1)\end{align}$$

So, when you are given that one event occurs in the first three unit-times:

- How many do you expect will occur in the next unit-time? $~\mathsf E(N(4)\mid N(3)=1)$
- How many do you expect occurred in the first two unit-times?  $~\mathsf E(N(2)\mid N(3)=1)$

Comment: Thanks. But for part2, I am still confused. How do you split $E(N(4)-N(2)\mid N(3)=1) $ into two terms. It has been conditioned. This part confuses me.

Comment: @kuku Linearity of Expectation works for conditional expectation too.  $$\mathsf E(X+Y\mid Z=z) ~=~ \mathsf E(X\mid Z=z) + \mathsf E(Y\mid Z=z)$$

Comment: The first term: $E(N(4)|N(3)=1)=1+\lambda$.

Comment: I have some problem with the second term. $E(N(2)|N(3)=1)$. This conditional poisson would be uniform distributed between $[0,3]$. Therefore, between the interval [0,2], it would have probability of $2/3$. Between [2,3], it would have probability $1/3$. Therefore, I guess $E(N(2)|N(3)=1)=2/3$ .

Comment: @kuku  $~\color{green}\checkmark~$ Yes, to both.